# Can gitversion be made to apply a unique tag to an existing tagged commit?

Tags: git, git-flow, semantic-versioning, gitversion, git-history

Following the gitflow branching model on a project, my "development branch" is named `dev`, my release branches are prefixed with `release/`, and my "production branch" is `master`.

Our CI/CD process uses **gitversion** to apply an alpha-tag (e.g. `0.2.0-alpha.12`) to each commit to the `dev` branch.

When I am ready to make a release, I create a release-branch from a desired commit on the `dev` branch, push it to the remote, and our CI/CD process uses **gitversion** to apply a beta-tag (e.g. `0.2.0-beta.1`) to the commit.

We currently do not have any `GitVersion.yml` -- the problem description below is from the default behavior of **gitversion**.

**Problem:**
When **gitversion** is applied to a commit that has an existing tag, it returns the existing commit, not a new one.
E.g. the `dev` commit from which the `release/0.2.0` branch created, is tagged with `0.2.0-alpha.12`. When **gitversion** is run on the newly-created `release/0.2.0` branch, the tag it returns is `0.2.0-alpha.12`, instead of a new beta-tag.

**Desired result:**
**gitversion** can be made to generate a unique tag for an existing commit with an existing tag.
E.g. When **gitversion** is run on the newly-created `release/0.2.0` branch, the tag it returns is `0.2.0-beta.1` regardless that the commit is already tagged with `0.2.0-alpha.12`.

**Question:**
Can **gitversion** be configured to achieve the desired result, i.e. generate a new beta-tag if run on a release-branch that points to an existing alpha-tagged commit? (I have a decent -- probably not expert -- understanding of git branching and tagging: I understand that in the described scenario, two branches are pointing to the same commit).

As context to this question: our CI/CD process relies on the `"SemVer"` element of **gitversion**'s output to decide what tag to apply. When newly-pushed release-branches point to existing dev-branch commits (which will have existing alpha-tags), it trips (or desired behavior is not achieved) because the **gitversion**-generated tag for the release-branch is the existing alpha-tag, instead of the desired new beta-tag.

As illustration:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:7999/prj/repo.git
$ git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
$ git log --oneline -n 1 --decorate
0593fb2 (HEAD -> dev, tag: 0.2.0-alpha.12, origin/dev, release/0.2.0) A useful comment.
$ docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" artifactory.company.com/gitversion:5.7.1 /repo
{
...
  "SemVer": "0.2.0-alpha.12",
...
}
$ git checkout -b release/0.2.0
Switched to a new branch 'release/0.2.0'
$ docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" artifactory.company.com/gitversion:5.7.1 /repo
{
...
  "SemVer": "0.2.0-alpha.12",
...
}
```

**What I've tried:**
Typically, I make and commit a change on the newly-created release-branch, in order to generate a new commit that is unique to the release-branch, then run **gitversion** on this commit. This generates a desired beta-tag. E.g.:

```
$ touch foo.bar && git add --all && git commit -m "wip" && git log --oneline -n 2 --decorate
[release/0.2.0 98435eb] wip
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo.bar
98435eb (HEAD -> release/0.2.0) wip
0593fb2 (tag: 0.2.0-alpha.12, origin/dev, dev) A useful comment.
$ docker run -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) --rm -v "$(pwd):/repo" artifactory.company.com/gitversion:5.7.1 /repo
{
...
  "SemVer": "0.2.0-beta.1",
...
}
```

However, this is often undesirable because the dev-branch commit is perfect as-is, and I've needed to do contrived work.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the [Gitversion issue](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20release) does not mention this, I would make sure the CICD execute a script which, in its workspace (where the repository is cloned), it:

- delete any alpha-tag on a release branch HEAD
- call `gitversion`, which should return the right beta tag.

It is a workaround, but at least no new commit needed.